# Optional generic typed parameters cannot be inferred

Tags: c#, generics, optional-parameters

I had a method definition like this:

```
public List<TEntity> GetAll<T> (
    params Expression<Func<TEntity, T>>[] fieldsToExclude )
{
    ...
}
```

But when I make it like this I can't have different types.

So I have changed it to this:

```
public List<TEntity> GetAll<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8> (
    Expression<Func<TEntity, T1>> field1ToExclude,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, T2>> field2ToExclude = null,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, T3>> field3ToExclude = null,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, T4>> field4ToExclude = null,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, T5>> field5ToExclude = null,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, T6>> field6ToExclude = null,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, T7>> field7ToExclude = null,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, T8>> field8ToExclude = null )
{
    ...
}
```

And I try to use it like:

```
var allItems = GetAll(p => p.SomeProperty1, p => p.SomeProperty2);
```

But now on client side it says:

> Type arguments '...' cannot be inferred from the usage.

It makes sense since I don't use the optional paramters at all. When I give all parameters it works fine, but optionality makes it erroneous.

Creating many methods with a telescoping parameters is a way out. But there must be a neater way too I suppose. How can I provide this functionality?

Comment: You'll have to go with `params Expression<Func<TEntity, Object>>[] fieldsToExclude` and (assuming it's EntityFramework provider you're passing those expressions to) deal with the actual expression type casting.

Comment: Basically has not solution. The typical workaround is to use `params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[]` and deal with `Expression.Convert` introduced for value types.

Comment: well it's not EntityFramework provider, hence I don't have to deal with the type casting. I just use the name of the field and I wasn't actually using any of the `T`s. Hence this should actually work. You should post it as answer @haim770.

Comment: As an aside, calling a method `GetAll` and then passing it things you *don't* want is violently unintuitive. Consider something like `GetAllWithExcludedProperties`.

Comment: That's a constructive critisicm @JeroenMostert, thank you.

Comment: Even if you need just the names (I guess from `MemberExpression`), you still need to deal (strip) the `Expression.Convert`

Comment: Yes @IvanStoev but it is already taken care of.

Comment: Good. Although it shouldn't exist before changing `T` to `object`. Anyway.

Comment: Well I wasn't extracting the types name, i was extracting the fields name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can settle with your expressions returning `Object`, you can simply omit the generic argument and use `Object` instead:

```
public List<TEntity> GetAll<TEntity> (params Expression<Func<TEntity, Object>>[] fieldsToExclude)
{
    ...
}
```